# How to move to different directory in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

So basically I have a *jenkins* installed on my server. I need to run test cases first and then deploy it on other directory. how can I move to another directory 
pull the code there or move the files? I need to put it in /var/www

Here's my *Jenkinsfile*

```
node {
    stage('build') {
        sh 'composer install'
        sh 'cp .env.example .env'
        sh 'php artisan migrate'
        sh 'php artisan key:generate'
        sh 'php artisan config:clear'
        sh 'php artisan key:clear'
    }
    stage('integration_testing') {
        sh 'vendor/bin/phpunit'
    }
    stage('deploy') {
        sh 'deploy in /var/www'
    }
}
```

Update

so this is what I did

```
dir('/var/www/app') { // this app is also a repository of the app
        stage('deploy') {
            echo 'Deploying...'
            checkout scm // or using git pull origin branch ( i'm having an error )
```

Comment: With the option `dir` you can change to other directories in your code. So if you wrap your deploy stage in ```dir('var/www') { stage('deploy') { ....... } }```, you change the directory where you run your deploy script. To copy files you can use File Operations plugin or some sh commands to move files to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for everyone who use CI/CD like this

I use

```
dir('/var/www/app') { // this app is also a repository of the app
    stage('deploy') {
        echo 'Deploying...'
        git (
            url: 'your-git',
            credentialsId: 'git-cred', // the credentials you created in your jenkins
            branch: 'dev'
        )
```

then just adjust the folder premissions in /var/www/app

Comment: Trying to put `dir()` outside of `stage()` gives me an error. `WorkflowScript: 21: Expected a stage @ line 21, column 9.`. Putting inside the stage works, but means you need to include every time.